# I have run into an error with my testing, i have compiled and migrated . i ran 'truffle test' and i have this error

Tags: javascript, blockchain, solidity, chai, truffle

```js
const {assert} = require ('chai')
// const { Item } = require('react-bootstrap/lib/Breadcrumb')
const KryptoBird = artifacts.require('./KryptoBird');

// check for chai

require('chai')
.use(require('chai-as-promised'))
.should()
contract ('KryptoBird',(accounts) => {
    let contract

    // Testing Container

    describe('deployment',async() => {
        // test Sample 
        it('deploys successfully',async() => {

           contract = await KryptoBird.deployed()
           const address = contract.address;
           assert.notEqual(address,'')
           assert.notEqual(address, null)
           assert.notEqual(address, undefined)
           assert.notEqual(address, 0x0)
        })
    })
})
```

i run in this error in my terminal
\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\node_modules\idna-uts46-hx\idna-map.js:681
new Uint32Array([2113345,0,2098209,211113

SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
at compileFunction ()
at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:352:18)
at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1031:15)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1065:27)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
at C:\Users\Daniel Awodeji\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\node_modules\idna-uts46-hx\uts46.js:9:51
at Object. (C:\Users\Daniel Awodeji\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\node_modules\idna-uts46-hx\uts46.js:14:2)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
Truffle v5.4.29 (core: 5.4.29)
Node v16.13.1

> `Blockquote`

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are forcing truffle test to look for your contract in your test file.

Just replace

`const KryptoBird = artifacts.require('./KryptoBird');`

with

`const KryptoBird = artifacts.require('KryptoBird');`